# Flutter button calls setState of other widget

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I'm getting serious about communication between the widgets in my app.

I have a bar that has three states: Information, copy mode and options. When in info, only the date is displayed with DateFormat(). When in options, the information is changed by two buttons: copy and paste. When the copy button is used then the content of the bar is changed to a single button (paste).

To switch between information and options states there is an animated button that alters the value of a provider.

The button that allows to change from one state to another is in a StatefulWidget. The bar is a StatelessWidget that has a Consumer that makes it rebuild every time the button changes value.

So far so good. However, I would like that when clicking the paste button (which is in the Stateless) the setState() method of the button is called so that inside it uses the animation controller and calls reverse()...

The button starts with a menu icon and then turns into a cross to close. The problem is that when using the paste button, the button stays on the cross, it does not return to show the menu icon.

This is the code...

The bar:

```
class OptionsBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const OptionsBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Consumer<OptionsBarProvider>(
              builder: (_, optionsController, __) => AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                child: optionsController.state == EditorState.copyMode
                    ? TextButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () {
                          optionsController.setState(EditorState.information);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.paste),
                        label: const Text('Pegar'))
                    : optionsController.state == EditorState.options
                        ? const ButtonsBar()
                        : Consumer<ShiftSystem>(
                            builder: (_, backend, __) => Text(
                              backend.getFormattedCurrentDay(),
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const OptionsBarButton(), // This is the button widget!
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The button:

```
class OptionsBarButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const OptionsBarButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OptionsBarButton> createState() => _OptionsBarButtonState();
}

class _OptionsBarButtonState extends State<OptionsBarButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final OptionsBarProvider optionsController =
        context.read<OptionsBarProvider>();

    return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (optionsController.state == EditorState.options ||
              optionsController.state == EditorState.copyMode) {
            optionsController.setState(EditorState.information);
          } else {
            optionsController.setState(EditorState.options);
          }

          setState(() {
            _isPlaying = !_isPlaying;
            if (_isPlaying) {
              _controller.forward();
            } else {
              _controller.reverse();
            }
          });
        },
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
          progress: _controller,
        ));
  }

  bool returnToMenuIcon() {
    setState(() => _controller.reverse());
    return true;
  }
}
```

The buttonBar:

```
class ButtonsBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const ButtonsBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final optionsController = context.read<OptionsBarProvider>();

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
            optionsController.setState(EditorState.copyMode);
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.copy),
          label: const Text('Copiar'),
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
          label: const Text('Eliminar'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The provider:

```
class OptionsBarProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late EditorState state;

  OptionsBarProvider() {
    state = EditorState.information;
  }

  bool get copyMode => state == EditorState.copyMode;

  void setState (EditorState value) {
    state = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please share the `ButtonBar` too? I cannot get the paste-button to show up with the code provided.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the code you should remove the `setState` in the build of `OptionsBarButton` and reverse or forward the animation depending on the `EditorState`. To listen for dependency changes, like the provider `EditorState`, override the [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) and only then call forward/reverse.

It should be this:

```dart
class OptionsBarButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const OptionsBarButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OptionsBarButton> createState() => _OptionsBarButtonState();
}

class _OptionsBarButtonState extends State<OptionsBarButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final OptionsBarProvider optionsController =
        context.read<OptionsBarProvider>();
    if (optionsController.state != EditorState.information) {
      _controller.forward();
    } else {
      _controller.reverse();
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final OptionsBarProvider optionsController =
        context.watch<OptionsBarProvider>();

    return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (optionsController.state == EditorState.options ||
              optionsController.state == EditorState.copyMode) {
            optionsController.setState(EditorState.information);
          } else {
            optionsController.setState(EditorState.options);
          }
        },
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
          progress: _controller,
        ));
  }

  bool returnToMenuIcon() {
    setState(() => _controller.reverse());
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea such a method existed, now a lot of things make sense. Thank you very much!!!